# Unable to select the right frame on 2d Blender

Tags: keyframes

I'm working on a short animation, and I have every key frame loaded up at the bottom of my screen. The only problem is, when I go to try to select a specific frame in order to do things like duplicate it, I'm unable to click the right frame. It always clicks one several frames to the left. It's nothing wrong with my laptop (to my knowledge), so is there a way to zoom into the frames on 2d blender? If not, can I highlight a single frame in some way that I don't already know? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from the Blender documentation:

**Adjusting the View**

The Timeline can be panned by holding MMB, then dragging the area left or right.

You can zoom the Timeline by using Ctrl-MMB, the mouse Wheel, or pressing NumpadMinus and NumpadPlus.

You can also use the scrollbars, located at the bottom or the right of the editor, to pan and zoom the view.

[https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/timeline.html#:~:text=The%20Timeline%20can%20be%20panned,pan%20and%20zoom%20the%20view](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/timeline.html#:%7E:text=The%20Timeline%20can%20be%20panned,pan%20and%20zoom%20the%20view).